# PhusionPassenger::UnknownError, Ruby on Rails application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-sign-on, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm using [Redmine SAML authentication plugin](https://github.com/cvaldemar/redmine_saml_auth) to integrate redmine with my application inorder to enable Single Sign On(SSO) in redmine which made it possible for users to login with the same username and password.
Following ruby and rails versions installed.

**ruby -v**: ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]

**rails -v**: Rails 4.2.0

Error message:

```
There are no gemspecs at /opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0. (Bundler::InvalidOption)
```

Exception class:

```
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

Application root:

```
/opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0
```

Backtrace:

```
#   File    Line    Location
0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb    56  in `gemspec'
1   /opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0/plugins/ruby-saml/Gemfile    3   in `eval_gemfile'
2   /opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0/Gemfile  104 in `glob'
3   /opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0/Gemfile  104 in `eval_gemfile'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb    7   in `evaluate'
5   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb 18  in `build'
6   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb    144 in `definition'
7   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb    112 in `setup'
8   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 326 in `prepare_app_process'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 176 in `initialize_server'
10  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in `report_app_init_status'
11  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 174 in `initialize_server'
12  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in `start_synchronously'
13  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in `start'
14  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 149 in `start'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 219 in `spawn_rails_application'
16  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in `lookup_or_add'
17  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 214 in `spawn_rails_application'
18  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `synchronize'
19  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
20  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 213 in `spawn_rails_application'
21  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 132 in `spawn_application'
22  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in `handle_spawn_application'
23  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `__send__'
24  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `server_main_loop'
25  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in `start_synchronously'
26  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99
```

Appriciate any help regarding the error, or suggestions on different method of enabeling SSO in redmine.

**Update** :/opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0/Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "3.2.19"

gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.1"

gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"

gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]

gem "builder", ">= 3.0.4"

gem "request_store", "1.0.5"

gem "mime-types"

gem "rbpdf", "~> 1.18.1"

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication

group :ldap do

  gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"

end

# Optional gem for OpenID authentication

group :openid do

  gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.3.0", :require => "openid"

  gem "rack-openid"

end

platforms :mri, :mingw do

  # Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file, not supported with jruby

  group :rmagick do

    # RMagick 2 supports ruby 1.9

    # RMagick 1 would be fine for ruby 1.8 but Bundler does not support

    # different requirements for the same gem on different platforms

    gem "rmagick", ">= 2.0.0"

  end

  # Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby

  group :markdown do

    # TODO: upgrade to redcarpet 3.x when ruby1.8 support is dropped

    gem "redcarpet", "~> 2.3.0"

  end

end

platforms :jruby do

  # jruby-openssl is bundled with JRuby 1.7.0

  gem "jruby-openssl" if Object.const_defined?(:JRUBY_VERSION) && JRUBY_VERSION < '1.7.0'

  gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", "~> 1.3.2"

end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database

# configuration file

require 'erb'

require 'yaml'

                     database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")

if File.exist?(database_file)

  database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)

  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq

  if adapters.any?

    adapters.each do |adapter|

      case adapter

      when 'mysql2'

        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]

        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby

      when 'mysql'

        gem "mysql", "~> 2.8.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]

        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby

      when /postgresql/

        gem "pg", ">= 0.11.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]

        gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby

      when /sqlite3/

        gem "sqlite3", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]

        gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter", :platforms => :jruby

      when /sqlserver/

        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.6.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]

        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]

      else

        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")

      end

    end

  else

    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")

  end

else

  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")

end



group :development do

  gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2"

  gem "yard"

end

group :test do

  gem "shoulda", "~> 3.3.2"

  gem "shoulda-matchers", "1.4.1"

  gem "mocha", "~> 1.0.0", :require => 'mocha/api'

  if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.3'

    gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"

    gem "selenium-webdriver"

  end

end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")

if File.exists?(local_gemfile)

  puts "Loading Gemfile.local ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`

  instance_eval File.read(local_gemfile)

end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles

Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|

  puts "Loading #{file} ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`

  #TODO: switch to "eval_gemfile file" when bundler >= 1.2.0 will be required (rails 4)

  instance_eval File.read(file), file

end
```

**Update**: /opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0/plugins/ruby-saml/Gemfile

```
group :test do

  if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"

    gem "nokogiri",   "~> 1.5.0"

    gem "ruby-debug", "~> 0.10.4"

  elsif RUBY_VERSION < "2.0"

    gem "debugger-linecache", "~> 1.2.0"

    gem "debugger", "~> 1.6.4"

  else

    gem "byebug",   "~> 2.1.1"

  end

  gem "shoulda",    "~> 2.11"

  gem "rake",       "~> 10"

  gem "mocha",      "~> 0.14",  :require => false

  gem "timecop",    "<= 0.6.0"

  gem "systemu",    "~> 2"

  gem "rspec",      "~> 2"

end
```

Comment: From a 30000 foot overlook of the situation, it appears that you are attempting to add a plugin that hasn't been updated in 3 years, could possibly just be an instance of incompatibility between the plugin and the Redmine and/or Rails version

Comment: From the stacktrace, it seems that Rails loads a Gemfile from the saml plugin. However, the plugin you linked to doesn't have a file. Thus, you probably have added one with invalid syntax. Thus, please share the file in `/opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0/plugins/ruby-saml/Gemfile`.

Comment: @HolgerJust, I have shared the Gemfile.

Comment: Looks like some gem (probably nokogiri) in your plugin's Gemfile conflicts with other specifications. For production use, I'd rather remove the complete Gemfile in the plugin as it only specifies gems for testing.

Comment: @HolgerJust, thanks. I'm getting error when trying to do: 
`sudo gem install ruby-saml
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-saml:
 nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.`

Because of that I think below error comes,
Error message:
`no such file to load -- ruby-saml`
Exception class:
`LoadError`
Application root:
`/opt/redmine/redmine-2.6.0`